# XCode Wait Cursor display

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nscursor

I want display wait cursor when user click on button and then normal cursor when 
operations are end.
How can i do ?
I read on mac developer center that wait cursor is native.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this Youtube video helps: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8G6nSHAgak

Or for iOS apps use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
```

and

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
```

Comment: Instead of only providing link to a video that may or not answer the question, post the solution instead. See [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: Listen, I want wheel cursor when user click on button and then I want normal cursor when operation is end.